# MobFox iOS Framework, Crashes When XIB unloaded... what am I doing wrong here?

Tags: objective-c, ios, crash, ads

A quick rundown of whats happening here.

I've got a GameScene and a GameOverUIController. When Game ends, It loads the GameOverUIController, which loads the xib, which loads the MobFoxBannerView.

Here's the issue: If you push the "play again" button to fast or you play a round longer than about 3 minutes, the ad loads in the background but essentially has no where to go, and crashes.

I took a friends advice of adding the ViewDidUnload to set the bannerview to nil, but it still crashes... I'm not the most amazing programmer admitted, but I feel like I'm making the dumbest error somewhere... Any help is greatly appreciated. Am I just using the wrong syntax on something here?

I've done the following things.

I synthesize bannerView on the GameOverUI Implementation.

Manually adding it to the view now, before I had added a UIwebview directly to xib Interface builder for GameOverUIController

```
self.bannerView = [[[MobFoxBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)] autorelease]; 
bannerView.delegate = self;

[self.view addSubview:bannerView];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:bannerView];
```

And thats in my main implementation. So everytime it loads the GameOver Screen it requests a new add.

Then I set the values in the header file.

```
-(NSString *) publisherIdForMobFoxBannerView:(MobFoxBannerView *)banner;

@property (nonatomic, retain) MobFoxBannerView *bannerView;
```

and set my publisher ID in the the bottom of GameOverUIController.m

```
- (NSString *)publisherIdForMobFoxBannerView:(MobFoxBannerView *)banner
{
return @"xxxxxxxxxxxx";
}
```

Then... STILL get a crash so then I tried to set it to nil hoping that would work... but I'm not sure about the syntax...

On GameOverUIController.m

```
- (void)viewDidUnload
{

[super viewDidUnload];

self.bannerView = nil;
// or ? bannerView.delegate = nil;
}
```

Niether of those lines works..... I'm at a total loss. Going to move onto another ads platform unless I can figure this out before the weekend is over. Bane of my existence right now. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much

Edit:

Figured it out...
Had nothing to do with ViewUnload....

```
- (void)dealloc
{
bannerView.delegate = nil;
[super dealloc];

}
```

Was adding it to the wrong location... Works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is in

```
bannerView.delegate = self;
```

- when add is loaded (because of bad internet it can be very slow for instance) - delegate method is being called, but "self" is released - so runtime exception is thrown.

By the way, I don't know a thing about MobFox framework. It's just a common anti-pattern.